# Unable to connect to GoDaddy hosted data base with even with correct string

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, web-deployment

Following is my connection string to database at goDaddy machine.

```
Data Source=<ipaddress>;Initial Catalog=<dbName>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<userid>;Password=<pw>
```

Now funny thing is same string does work on local machine. to fire any query via visual studio. The change also gets reflected in myLittle Admin on godaddy server. but when I put it into web config file of the website, each operation throws 500 : Internal server error. Can you help me on this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBCS"
         connectionString ="<cs>"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="DBCSProd"
         connectionString ="<cs>"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="DBCSLocal"
         connectionString ="<cs>"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="CalculatorWebServiceSoap" allowCookies ="True"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4661/WebServices/CalculatorWebService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CalculatorWebServiceSoap"
                contract="CalculatorAdd.CalculatorWebServiceSoap" name="CalculatorWebServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried to takeout system.service model. But no use.

### Edit : following are headers from network tab

```
**General**
Request URL:http://<website>/<path>/checkDeliverableArea.asmx/checkDeliverableAreasBool
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:50.62.160.127:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade


**Response Headers**
**view source**
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:3420
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 02 Oct 2017 14:42:11 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk:PleskWin
**view (source)**
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Mon, 02 Oct 2017 14:42:11 GMT
Content-Length: 3420


**Request Headers**
**view (parsed)**
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-IN,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:22
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.241910055.1503834936; _gid=GA1.2.1810498430.1506838482
Host:qa.pocketfarms.in
Origin:http://qa.pocketfarms.in
Referer:http://qa.pocketfarms.in/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
**view(source)**
POST /WebService/Common/checkDeliverableArea.asmx/checkDeliverableAreasBool HTTP/1.1
Host: qa.pocketfarms.in
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://qa.pocketfarms.in
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://qa.pocketfarms.in/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-IN,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.241910055.1503834936; _gid=GA1.2.1810498430.1506838482

**Form Data**
view (source)
view URL encoded
LookupParameter:411019
```

Comment: You should turn on remote errors to find out what exactly happens. Could well be that simply your web.config there is broken.

Comment: It works correctly on my home machine, but not on godaddy server. I also checked framework version used by the website. Which turned out to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using web services,and getting internal server error 500 place this code in your web config and try again.

```
`<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>`
```

Comment: I added the xml to the config file but it didnt work.

Comment: Open developer tool of the browser , go to the console tab and see the inner exception details of the internal server error 500 and let me know the details

Comment: I couldnt add the whole details in the comment, I have added by editing the description. Please take a look.

Comment: Your edited description does not provide the complete error message. Can you perform the following steps and provide me complete details.                     1. place a debugger in error block of your ajax code.                                        2. Run your application and open developer tool in browser.                              3. Explore the error object and see the details of error message.                   4.provide those detail error message.                                                                    As because internal server error 500 can came due to many reasons

Comment: `{"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at checkDeliverableArea.checkDeliverableAreasBool(String LookupParameter) in g:\\pleskvhosts\\pocketfarms.in\\qa.pocketfarms.in\\App_Code\\CheckDeliverableArea.cs:line 61","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"}`

Line 61 is connection. its probably not picking up the connection string defined in web config on prod environment. Though, the connection string is correct and the same, plus line 61 works on local.

Comment: As it says its a null reference error means there is a variable who has null in it ...might be this line of code returns null checkDeliverableArea.checkDeliverableAreasBool(String LookupParameter).. or the piece of code written  inside this method "checkDeliverableAreasBool" has some null value